# Python + BigQuery + ResponseNotReady()

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am using "bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)" and it is executing correctly in my laptop, but when I am executing this query on the server I am getting the following error.

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "QueryAPI.py", line 117, in localMain
    exportDataToGCS(canonicalDate);
  File "QueryAPI.py", line 177, in exportDataToGCS
    bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
  File "/homeBigQuery/src/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/homeBigQuery/src/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 198, in build
    resp, content = http.request(requested_url)
  File "/homeBigQuery/src/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/homeBigQuery/src/oauth2client/client.py", line 538, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/homeBigQuery/src/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/homeBigQuery/src/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/homeBigQuery/src/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1286, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 980, in getresponse
    raise ResponseNotReady()
```

Comment: Solved this. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by specifying the proxy server host and port for the server that I was running this on. While initiating an authorized http service object with the help of credentials, I modified the code as follows:

BEFORE:

```
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
```

FIX:

```
http = httplib2.Http(proxy_info = httplib2.ProxyInfo(httplib2.socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, 'your-proxy-host-name', your-proxy-port))
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try [this 3rd party library for BigQuery](https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python). It's a thin wrapper around the Google BigQuery API.

To login to BigQuery:

```
import bigquery as bq

with open('my_key.pem', 'r') as key:
    key_content = key.read()

bq_client = bq.get_client(project_id='foo',
                          service_account='bar',
                          private_key=key_content)
```

To submit a load job:

```
schema = [{'name':'foo', 'type':'STRING'}]
job = bq_client.import_data_from_uris(source_uris=['gs://foo/bar'],
                                        dataset='foo',
                                        table='bar',
                                        schema=schema,
                                        source_format=bq.client.JOB_FORMAT_CSV,
                                        write_disposition=bq.client.JOB_WRITE_TRUNCATE,
                                        field_delimiter=',',
                                        skip_leading_rows=1)


try:
    job_resource = bq_client.wait_for_job(job, timeout=60)        
except bq.errors.BigQueryTimeoutException:
    logging.critical('BigQuery loading timeout.')
```

Comment: Thanks. Will check out this 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the "http=http" parameter ?

here is an example of the use of the BQ API:

```
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# REPLACE WITH YOUR Project ID
PROJECT_NUMBER = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
# REPLACE WITH THE SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL FROM GOOGLE DEV CONSOLE
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

# OBTAIN THE KEY FROM THE GOOGLE APIs CONSOLE
# More instructions here: http://goo.gl/w0YA0
f = file('key.p12', 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    key,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('bigquery', 'v2')
datasets = service.datasets()
response = datasets.list(projectId=PROJECT_NUMBER).execute(http)

print 'Dataset list:'
for dataset in response['datasets']:
  print '%s' % dataset['datasetReference']['datasetId']
```